# PyInstaller collect package issue (Google Analytics)?

Tags: python

I have the below imports:

```
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
```

I'm trying to make a single file exe file by running:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w --icon=icon.ico --add-data client_secrets.json;. main.py  --collect-data "google-api-python-client" --collect-data "oauth2client";.
```

I also tried:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w --icon=icon.ico --add-data client_secrets.json;. main.py  --collect-data google-api-python-client --collect-data oauth2client;.
```

But when i run the exe file I get the error:

```
  Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception: name analytics version: v3
  File "main.py", line 81, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 32, in get_service
  File "googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
  File "googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 287, in build
  File "googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 404, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: analytics  version: v3
```

The script works fine as a python file.

How to reproduce:

```
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def get_service(api_name, api_version, scopes, key_file_location):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
            key_file_location, scopes=scopes)

    # Build the service object.
    # service = build(api_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
    service = discovery.build(api_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
    return service

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit'
    # client_secret from console.cloud.google.com
    key_file_location = f'{dir_path}/client_secrets.json'

    # Authenticate and construct service.
    service = get_service(
            api_name='analytics',
            api_version='v3',
            scopes=[scope],
            key_file_location=key_file_location)
```

Comment: this isn't an issue with pyinstaller.  It appears there is something wrong with your api name or credentials.  You can try setting `static_discover=False` in the `discover.build` call. But I have no clue if that will work.

Comment: @Alexander thank you! You were very close, I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `static_discovery=False` to discovery.build

Example:

```
service = discovery.build(api_name, api_version, credentials=credentials, static_discovery=False)
```

then run pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w --icon=icon.ico --add-data client_secrets.json;. main.py  --collect-data google-api-python-client --collect-data oauth2client;.
```